# Assembly language big addition and, multiplication and division

Tags: assembly, emu8086, microprocessors

Perform the following arithmetic operation: (1 + 2) * (3 – 1) / 5 + 3 + 2 – (1 * 2) how to solve this in a assembly language

Comment: `mov ax, 4`. But seriously, which part is causing you problem?

Comment: How is that "big addition" or "big multiplication"?  The numbers are tiny (easily fitting in 8 bits), no extended-precision required.

Comment: No, actually i was tired giving good header or starting what ever they call. what ever i am giving it, it says already there is a same named problem or name is taken or something. I need the solution quickly as i have assignment to do. But i figure it out my self. @Jester

Comment: i was looking for assembly code @PeterCordes

Answer (score 2):

I'd solve it like this:

```
    mov ax, (1 + 2) * (3 – 1) / 5 + 3 + 2 – (1 * 2)
```

Most assemblers are smart enough to do the calculation for you, and because none of the values change there's no reason to waste CPU time doing it every time the software is executed.

For something like "`(a + b) * (c – d) / e + f + g – (h * i)`" (where everything is variables and nothing can be calculated before its executed) it ends up being some relatively trivial instructions (`add` or `lea`, `sub`, `mul` or `imul`, `div` or `idiv`) with a bunch of headaches figuring out where the variables actually are in memory.